# Why string data is not moved to target but vector was

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I have below code:

```
class string
{
    std::string data;

public:

    string()
    {
        data = "Hello";
    }
    string(const string& that)
    {
        data = std::move(that.data);
        std::cout << data << " and that.data " << that.data;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    std::cout << "vec size = " << vec.size() << std::endl;
    std::vector<int> nvec = std::move(vec);
    std::cout << "nvec size = " << nvec.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "vec size = " << vec.size() << std::endl;
    string s;
    string s1(s);
}
```

The output of code is:

```
vec size = 5                                                                                                            
nvec size = 5                                                                                                           
vec size = 0                                                                                                            
Hello and that.data Hello
```

Why did not the that.data moved to target data as like nvec and vec?

Comment: Const objects are not movable. You can learn this in any modern C++ book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're declaring the parameter `that` as `const`. As the result, `data = std::move(that.data);` calls the copy assignment operator, not move assignment operator. Move operation is supposed to perform modifications on the object to be moved, which shouldn't be `const`.

You could change the parameter type to rvalue-reference (to non-const).

```
string(string&& that)
{
    data = std::move(that.data);
    std::cout << data << " and that.data " << that.data;
}
```

then

```
string s;
string s1(std::move(s));
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/SwqAVKH33oRTMCDt)